# 2 Background images with separate animations?

Tags: css, background-image

This is bugging me, because I know that this is possible, I just don't really know how to write it properly. Here's an image of my vision:

[image]

So far in my css, I've implemented the cloud animation

```
#home{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 327px;
height: 57.78vh;    
background: #6bbfff url('../images/clouds.png') repeat-x fixed 50% 10%;
text-align: center;
-webkit-animation: cloudmove 180s infinite linear;
animation: cloudmove 180s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes cloudmove{
    0%   { background-position: 0% 10%; }
    100% { background-position: 100% 10%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloudmove{
    0%   { background-position: 0% 10%; }
    100% { background-position: 500% 10%; }
}
```

I've been trying to add the landscape illustration in the image shown above as background image number 2, but I'm having trouble. How do I get the css animation to not apply to it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just add another element which gets the second background image?

Comment: what do you mean? Layer 2 divs on top of each other? That's not ideal for a responsive design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this:

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hvfr8aq/1/)

Your pertinent CSS relies on some new features of backgrounds in CSS3.

**Layered background images**

You can instantiate these like so:

```
.my-rule {
  background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png);
  background-position: 0 0, 50% 50%;
}
```

It's pretty simple!  You just need to separate all rules for each respective background image with commas.  That goes straight down to your animations as well, like so:

```
@keyframes cloudmove{
    0%   { background-position: 0% 10%, 0% 0%; }
    100% { background-position: 100% 10%, 100% 0%; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloudmove{
    0%   { background-position: 0% 10%, 0% 0%; }
    100% { background-position: 500% 10%, 100% 0%; }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Haha thanks alot, I was thinking it was going to be so much more complicated but apparently this is the way you're supposed to do it! Still quite new to keyframe animations!

Comment: Nope, just that simple.